Hooks for specific scenario
My SpecFlow automation scripts perform test on web applications. Web browser will be launched and user name and password will be entered to login and then the test continues.
In my hooks class,
The [Before feature] hook and gets the required user name and password. Let's call the username, userA.
The [Before Scenario] hook launched the browser.
The Background keyword step does the login using the user name and password in the web browser.
However for 1 scenario, the user name  has to be a different user(userB) but since the [Before feature] hook is calling userA, I'm not able to login using userB.
Is there a way for the hook to call userB only for that 1 test scenario? Or are there any other ways to do this?

This is why I typically like including the user login step in the scenario:
Scenario: ...
    Given ...
    And ...
    And ...
    And ...
    And user "XYZ" has logged in
    When ...
    Then ...

It is the cost of one line of gherkin per scenario. If you don't want to hard code the username in each scenario, consider phrasing the "log in" step to focus on the role that user plays in the scenario. The step definition can handle which username and password is necessary to log in.
Say, for example, you are testing an blog web application. You have two users, one who write blogs posts, and another who comments on blog posts. Rather than:
Given user "xxx" has logged in

Phrase the step to focus on the role that user plays in the system. Something like:
Given a blog post author has logged in
Given a blog post commentator has logged in

This makes the scenario more explicit, but also gives you one place to put the username and password in your step definitions. If the username or password ever needs to change for one of those roles, you update the step definition instead of lord knows how many scenarios across who knows how many feature files.
